# RecyclerView howto

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used combination of RecyclerView, i.e.: When we open the Google play store, we can scroll the items horizontally and vertically to find an application.

My problem: When I click the parent View, it gives me the position of the parent; however, when I click the child View, I get the child position (Note: when I click the child View, I need the parent position).

I want my app to work the same as the Google play store so that when I click the child View it gives me the parent position.

Comment: Please [read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about adding urgent begging to questions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one main recylerview to display vertical list and within this, you can use one more recylerview with horizontal layout manager.